# No webGL in Chromium for Radeon Xpress 1250 (RS600M) in Raring

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, xubuntu, radeon

Before I say anything else, here's my lspci response:

```
$ lspci | grep 'VGA'
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[AMD/ATI] RS600M [Radeon Xpress 1250]
```

I'm running xubuntu, here's the output of my release from shell:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

The problem is that my generic drivers are working for the most part, but I don't have openGL or WebGL compatability on any browser. This isn't a huge problem, I'm not really trying to use this laptop for much, but I am a web developer and was hoping this would be more stable than the Win7 that was on it.

ATI/AMD no longer support this particular device, I've already downloaded the proprietary catalyst suite and run it, and got "your device is not supported." Are there any third-party or OS drivers out there that will at the very least support webGL so I can test canvas/css3 in-browser? Here's the output of my chrome://gpu about the driver, btw:

```
GL_VERSION  2.1 Mesa 9.1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Bah. I hate answering my own question, but here goes:

As it turns out, chromium happens to just disable webGL for my particular hardware configuration. It is supported, it's just forced off. I had to go to about:flags, and then enable "override software rendering."

BE WARNED: this apparently is pretty crash-prone but I haven't seen it happen yet. So for the time being I'll leave this answer here but not select it if someone can come up with a better driver that is not as crash prone... but that might not be a problem at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the open source drivers are probably the best you are going to get for now. I have the same problem with my AMD 4650 card. It got moved to the legacy driver branch and doesn't work really well with recent Ubuntu versions anymore.

For me the open source drivers work just fine (but do have some power management issues..) and even Steam games generally run very well. Just like you, I also forced 3D acceleration in Google Chrome and have yet to come by any crashed caused by it. I think it's stable enough!